# MySQL 5.7 default install running much slower than 5.6

Tags: mysql

I have a java / spring / hibernate app running with connections to a MySQL db.

We recently upgraded from 5.6 to 5.7 (on a Windows server) and the app has gone from taking 3 hours to 3 days to complete.  It essentially uses hibernate connections to retrieve read only data from the db before processing it and dumping the result elsewhere.

However as a first step, partly to check it was the upgraded version that is causing the problem, I installed 5.7.21 on my dev machine.  I then noticed that even doing a db restore took several hours rather than what used to take about 10 minutes on 5.6.  This has lead me to believe it may be more of a config issue than 'drivers' being out of date (I did think my first step was going to be upgrading app dependencies).  I didn't install the server but I installed my dev machine with a default 'developer' install.  Both the server and the dev machine are 64 bit Windows.

I've had a scoot around for obvious gotchas and not found anything yet.  I just wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction before I start seriously thrashing about ?  I have a good basic understanding of out of the box MySQL but I haven't done much config so even pointers to likely suspects in my.ini and best ways to investigate would be helpful.

Comment: Look for `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. Query MySQL first with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb_buffer_pool%';`. You want this one to be as high as possible, it controls amount of RAM that MySQL is allowed to allocate for I/O operations, so it avoids hitting the disk. It's the usual culprit, it could be that the upgrade overwrote the old value with default value.

Comment: That's great thanks.  Do you want to make it an answer or should I delete the question ?

Comment: Other people might have the same problem, I made it an answer and if it that was it - excellent ,we got the culprit, glad you sorted it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When upgrading, pay attention to `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable value.

It controls how much memory MySQL uses to make I/O operations faster. Usually, this is the one that makes it fly or that makes it crawl like a snail. There's a lot to be written about this particular variable, there's a plethora of excellent blog posts about it so I'll avoid explaining it into detail.

To see the current value, type in MySQL terminal:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%innodb_buffer_pool%';
```

Change the value in config file and restart MySQL.

For the value, don't go overboard, don't exceed your entire RAM. You want it as high as possible, especially for servers with a lot of data.